# Can I "pre-transpile" a node module and mix it in with browser-friendly JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have this basic code (could be **any** NPM package):

```
var Prismic = require('prismic.io');
Prismic.api(/*......*/)

/* Do something with the data returned from Prismic.api */
```

The problem is that in order to make this code work in the browser, I have to transpile it with Webpack or something (because of `require`).

I want to know:

Is it possible to replace `require('prismic.io')` some 100KB line of text so that I can run this code right in the browser? Can I somehow "pre-transpile" it and paste the result in line 1?

Comment: actually the WebPack is doing that what you've asked in your question, so what's the point of looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, you'd have to copy and paste the code of the library and modify it a bit, i.e. the part where it uses module.exports you'd have to replace with something that puts Prismic in the global scope, e.g. `window.Prismic = Prismic`

I would not recommend it, it is not that hard to set up a webpack build to use the required module.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I moved all my JS files into webpack and it's working great. However, might the answer to my question simply `be window.Prismic = Prismic` instead of `module.exports = Prismic` ?